# Every time I try to push something to my repo I get "warning: url has no scheme: github.com fatal: credential url cannot be parsed: github.com"

Tags: git

I can't push anything via git terminal. I'm always getting this message (warning: url has no scheme: github.com fatal: credential url cannot be parsed: github.com)
I've already tried deleting git purging all git files. Remaking configs but nothing helped.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote get-url origin`? It should start with `https://` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

A [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) (or sometimes [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)) has a general syntax, which, as shown in the linked Wikipedia articles, has the form:

> URI = scheme ":" ["//" authority] path ["?" query] ["#" fragment]

The "scheme" part of this is the literal string `http`, `https`, `ssh`, `ftp`, and so on.  Git in particular accepts both `https://` and `git://` URLs/URIs.

You're failing to provide either the `https://` *or* the `ssh://` part.  You have provided something like `github.com/user/repo.git`.  Git is telling you "stick the appropriate prefix on".

The prefix you choose will determine *how* Git goes about reaching out to `github.com` (via https, or via ssh).  Git does accept another way to write an ssh URL, but stick with the `ssh://` ones for now.